# How to make two column design responsive using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a responsive layout for my cover letter, and I have stumbled upon a problem regarding responsiveness.
Desktop layout looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9jnv.png).
However, I have opted for hiding the text as well as the progress bar in mobile views, but the margin on chips is not uniform as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7sXa.png).

I'm using this code for the computer skills section, since I figure that I can apply the solution to the section below. However, I will post more code if needed for context.

```
    <div className="grid grid-rows-4 grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 items-center justify-center w-full">
      <p className="text-center hidden md:block">Computer Skills</p>
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center">
        <CustomButton text="STUB1" />
        <ProgressBar width="w-full" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-1  m-2 sm:m-6" />
      <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center">
        <CustomButton text="STUB2" />
        <ProgressBar width="w-3/4" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-1 m-2 sm:m-6" />
      <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center mt-3 sm:mt-0">
        <CustomButton text="STUB3" />
        <ProgressBar width="w-3/4" />
      </div>
      <CustomLine ine isDashed="yes" />
    </div>
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this if there would be, any responsive issue, then make responsive your components, that would be any issue ...!

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-1 grid sm:grid-cols-12 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-4 items-center justify-center w-full">
  <p className="text-center hidden md:block">Computer Skills</p>
  <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center">
    <CustomButton text="STUB1" />
    <ProgressBar width="w-full" />
  </div>
  <div className="col-span-1  m-2 sm:m-6" />
  <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center">
    <CustomButton text="STUB2" />
    <ProgressBar width="w-3/4" />
  </div>
  <div className="col-span-1 m-2 sm:m-6" />
  <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center col-span-2 items-center mt-3 sm:mt-0">
    <CustomButton text="STUB3" />
    <ProgressBar width="w-3/4" />
  </div>
  <CustomLine ine isDashed="yes" />
</div>
```